# Show search hits

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

I'm trying to learn JavaScript, so I know that this isnt the best solution for a webshop but its only for learning. 
I'm making a search function, you search for a category and if you have a match, the result will show. I'm stuck at the last part. How am I gonna write the code so the result is shown?

Here's my code: (dont mind the showItem function, haven't started on that one yet)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var gallery = [
        {
            "img" : "img/gallery/gameboy2.png",
            "title" : "GameBoy Color [yellow]",
            "about" : "A-ball",
            "price" : 99,
            "category" : ["Gameboy", "color", "Console", "game"]

        },
        {
            "img" : "img/gallery/phone.png",
            "title" : "Hamburger Phone",
            "about" : "What is a smartphone?",
            "price" : 129,
            "category" : ["phone","hamburger"]
        },
        {
            "img" : "img/gallery/gameboy.png",
            "title" : "Nintendo GameBoy",
            "about" : "Things doesnt get better with time. This is the shit.",
            "price" : 499,
            "category" : ["Game","Console", "Gameboy"]
        },
        {
            "img" : "img/gallery/game2.png",
            "title" : "SEGA",
            "about" : "Things doesnt get better with time. This is the shit.",
            "price" : 699,
            "category" : ["Game","Console", "SEGA"]
        },
                    {
            "img" : "img/gallery/gameboy2.png",
            "title" : "GameBoy Color [yellow]",
            "about" : "A-ball",
            "price" : 99,
            "category" : ["Gameboy", "color", "Console", "game"]

        },
        {
            "img" : "img/gallery/phone.png",
            "title" : "Hamburger Phone",
            "about" : "What is a smartphone?",
            "price" : 129,
            "category" : ["phone","hamburger"]
        },
        {
            "img" : "img/gallery/gameboy.png",
            "title" : "Nintendo GameBoy",
            "about" : "Things doesnt get better with time. This is the shit.",
            "price" : 499,
            "category" : ["Game","Console", "Gameboy"]
        },
        {
            "img" : "img/gallery/game2.png",
            "title" : "SEGA",
            "about" : "Things doesnt get better with time. This is the shit.",
            "price" : 699,
            "category" : ["Game","Console", "SEGA"]
        }

 ];

 var search = document.getElementById("submit_search");
 search.addEventListener("click", searchItem);

 showItemsList();


 /*
     Create a li element and append to already existing ul
     Show an image of the product, and below the image show product title and price
 */

 function showItemsList() {

var ul = document.getElementById("product_list");

for(i =0; i < gallery.length; i++) {

    // get the current product
    var currentProduct = gallery[i];

    // create element li 
    var li = document.createElement('li');                           

    // create product img
    var productImg = document.createElement('img');
    productImg.src = currentProduct.img;
    productImg.className = "thumbnail";
    li.appendChild(productImg); 

    // create caption
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(currentProduct.title + " " + currentProduct.price + "kr"));                                         
    ul.appendChild(li);
}

}

/*
    If someone click on a product, show a larger picture with a caption telling about the product
    If you click the picture again, it minimize back to a thumbnail

*/
function showItem() {

}

/*
    A searchfield where you can choose between already existing categories. 
    Show only those items that been search for
*/
function searchItem() {
    var ul = document.getElementById("product_list");
    var search = document.getElementById("search").value;
    for(var x = 0; x < gallery.length; x++){
       //Get the current product
       var currentProduct = gallery[x];

       //get the current product categories
       var currentProductCategories = currentProduct.category;

       //Loop through each category
       for(var z = 0; z < currentProductCategories.length; z++){

        //Check if the category is the one we are looking for
        if(currentProductCategories[z] == search){

        }
    }
}
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let your `showItemsList` method accept your list as argument:

```
function showItemsList(items) {

var ul = document.getElementById("product_list");
ul.innerHTML = "";
for(i =0; i < items.length; i++) {

    // get the current product
    var currentProduct = items[i];

    // create element li 
    var li = document.createElement('li');                           

    // create product img
    var productImg = document.createElement('img');
    productImg.src = currentProduct.img;
    productImg.className = "thumbnail";
    li.appendChild(productImg); 

    // create caption
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(currentProduct.title + " " + currentProduct.price + "kr"));                                         
    ul.appendChild(li);
}

}
```

Now your `searchItem` method can use it:

```
function searchItem() {
    var matches = [];
    var ul = document.getElementById("product_list");
    var search = document.getElementById("search").value;
    for(var x = 0; x < gallery.length; x++){
       //Get the current product
       var currentProduct = gallery[x];

       //get the current product categories
       var currentProductCategories = currentProduct.category;

       //Loop through each category
       for(var z = 0; z < currentProductCategories.length; z++){

        //Check if the category is the one we are looking for
        if(currentProductCategories[z] == search){
           matches.push(currentProduct);
        }
       }
    }
    showItemsList(matches);
}
```

Comment: I tried this and the search function worked, but when i'm loading the page the gallery isnt showed to begin with...

Comment: Yes, of course you have to replace `showItemsList();` with `showItemsList(gallery);` at the beginning to pass your array...

Comment: I did that too, it says that _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined_ talking about this code `for(i =0; i < items.length; i++) {`

Comment: Make sure your `gallery` variable is set before calling `showItemsList(gallery);`

Comment: Its set at the beginning of the code, before the showItemsList is called. Should I change all your _list_ to _gallery_? Cuz thats what I did...